# How to add text to a variable in C?

Tags: c

I'm learning C at the moment and I run into some problem, hard to understand what is going on with variables and adding text to variable in C.

I know C is not treating the strings and character as in other programming language.
If I understand it correctly from my book:
I have to define a variable before I can use it, that's ok for me.
So, If I do this code, where I wish to print the variable text_1 it is failing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text_1[];
    text_1[] = "Testing";
    printf("Test 1 is: %s", text_1);
return(0);
}
```

But if I do this way, this is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char text_1[] = "Testing";
    printf("Test 1 is: %s", text_1);
return(0);
}
```

In some other programming language I can do this way:
Dim a as string

```
a="Testing"
print("Testing 1 is:", a) --> or similar option to print out the variable 'a'.
```

What is the correct way to do this in C?

Thank you.

Comment: The first way is wrong since you can't set an entire array in one operation, and you haven't even set the size of the array. You have to use a function like `strcpy`, to copy each individual characters in the string in the array.

Comment: or instead you can change the type of `text_1` to a `char *` instead, this way those assignments are allowed, but note that you can't modify the string after the assignment.

Comment: `char text_1[] = "Testing"`; is valid.  The compiler looks at the RHS and is able to compute that `text_1` needs to be (at least) 8 chars.  But `char text_1[];` is invalid, as the compiler has no way of knowing how large the array should be.  Try `char text_1[128];` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

Oops... C language is a rather low level language if you compare it to Java, Python or Ruby, or even Basic or JavaScript:

- it has no notion of text string but only uses *null terminated character arrays* in its standard library
- arrays by themselves are not first class citizens: except at initialization time, the language can only process arrays elements and not the full array

Long story made short, an array has a size that is defined only once (at definition time) and will never change during the life time of the array. `char text_1[] = "Testing";` is an idiomatic initialization: the size of the array is set to the number of characters of the literal string + 1 for the terminating null, so here 8. After that `text_1` will be able to contain other strings of at most 7 characters + 1 terminating null if you copy the relevant character for example with `strcpy`.

To go back to your code, `char text_1[];` declares an incomplete array with a declared size of 0 bytes. That means that you cannot use it. The 2 correct ways would be:

```
char text_1[] = "Testing";   // idiomatic initialization of a 8 characters array
```

or

```
char text_1[8];              // definition of an uninitialized char array of size 8
strcpy(text_1, "Testing");   // copy a string into the array
```

Not really sexy, but C language is like that...

Comment: I like the way you did it.
Is it a correct way to use this function strcpy() but not to look like and idiot? :-)
I mean, it is more pro look than to make a loop every time to counting the char and put them in an array just to "set up" a text in a variable. :-)

Comment: @Chris note the [8] , this includes one extra byte for the terminating '\0'. Its a common mistake for people to forget this. Also if you want to compose more fiddly strings use `snprintf`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for conclusion, what is the correct way to learn how to set up a variable with string in a way I can print it to the screen or use it for compare with other variables who are also holding strings?

I like this way but I'm not sure is it correct to use:

```
char * text_1;  // btw. what is this `*` meaning here?
text_1 = "Some text...";
printf("Variable text is: %s\n",text_1);
```

but this way is also acceptable by me:

```
char text_1[n];  // where n is a number of max char 
strcpy(text_1, "Some text...");
printf("Variable text is: %s\n",text_1);
```

Comment: Both are valid, but they are different, specifically the former string may not be writable. See [What is the difference between these initializations?](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html). More generally, you should take advantage of the many available C tutorials and books, and the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/index.html).